# Android 2.3.4 SSL problem

Tags: java, android, ssl

After upgrading to Android 2.3.4, I am getting following exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x*: I/O error during system call, Connection timed out
 at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
 at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:788)
```

Previous versions of Android were working OK. Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have specified SSL timeout explicitly and everything is working again:

```
val schemeRegistry = client.getConnectionManager.getSchemeRegistry
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getHttpSocketFactory(timeout,
      new SSLSessionCache(context)), 443))
```